# Sintech NGFF M.2 with MacBook Pro Retina 2013: Hibernation doesn't work

Tags: macbook, hibernate, samsung-ssd

I bought the *NGFF M.2 PCIe SSD Card as 2013 2014 2015 MacBook SSD adapter adapter* ([https://www.amazon.com/Sintech-Adapter-Upgrade-2013-2015-MacBook/dp/B01CWWAENG](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01CWWAENG)) and I'm using it with a Samsung EVO 970 on my MacBook Pro Retina 2013.

Installation went good as Internet Recovery Mode was even able to use the new SSD instantly. **But I had difficulties with the hibernation mode.** Mac OS 10.13 is able to boot but will alway freeze after the login screen (FileVault 2 is turned on).
I could solve this by changing hibernatemode to 0 (sleep without writing the RAM content on the SSD) and by setting standby to 0. Which means the notebook will never hibernate and the battery will continuously loose power. Basically it will be empty after 12h once it's unplugged in standby-mode.

**Now I'm wondering if an update to Mac OS 10.14 or 10.15 could solve the problem** as I have seen that SSD support was extended in those versions.
Has anybody tried this already?

Comment: This appears to be a reply with further questions to an existing QA. Stack Exchange is not a discussion forum & is not threaded like one. Without a clear link to the QA to which you are referring, there is no way for anyone to discover which it is.

Comment: Thank you @Tetsujin. Unfortunately somehow my unedited text (which I copied from a not answered mail to the manufacturer) was posted. So I updated the question.